PowerBI Report Server (On Premises)
Does anyone know how to embed power bi report (with parameter) into website?
Currently use iframe to embed, but the issue is, the parameter cannot be passed. And theres so many ways to embed for cloud (power bi service), but for on premises i found nothing. Please help
This is the embedded url
http://hisystem.ddns.me:8088/ReportsPowerBI/powerbi/UPLOADTEST/DirectSQL?rs:embed=true&rs:ParameterName=MonthParam&rs:ParameterName=YearParam&rs:ParameterName=DataStatusParam&rs:ParameterName=MonthParam&rs:ParameterName=YearParam&rs:ParameterName=DataStatusParam&rs:ParameterValue=04&rs:ParameterValue=2023&rs:ParameterValue=1
The reference sources is
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Report-Server/Power-BI-report-Server-on-premises-with-url-paramaters/m-p/4020491

I think you need to correct the structure of the URL for embedding with parameters in Power BI Report Server like below :
http://your-server-url/ReportsPowerBI/powerbi/YourReportPath?rs:embed=true&YourParameterName1=YourValue1&YourParameterName2=YourValue2
In your case, the issue might be that the parameters are being repeated incorrectly.
http://hisystem.ddns.me:8088/ReportsPowerBI/powerbi/UPLOADTEST/DirectSQL?rs:embed=true&MonthParam=04&YearParam=2023&DataStatusParam=1
In your iframe :
<iframe src="http://hisystem.ddns.me:8088/ReportsPowerBI/powerbi/UPLOADTEST/DirectSQL?rs:embed=true&MonthParam=04&YearParam=2023&DataStatusParam=1" width="800" height="600"></iframe>

